# java sbt test: exception ignored if test is run with SpringJUnit4ClassRunner

Tags: java, junit, sbt, spring-test

Got an issue when exception thrown by test is ignored by sbt and does not break the build.

Some code:

Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyConfig.class)
public class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    private ClassBeingTested sut;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        if (true)
            throw new Exception(); //it must break the build, but it doesn't
    }
}
```

If i remove SpringJUnit4ClassRunner and inject dependency myself it will break the build as expected.

If i forbid sbt to fork test process it will also break the build:

```
lazy val myProject = project.in(file("foo/proj"))
    .settings(....)
    .settings(sbt.Keys.fork in Test := false) <- the exception breaks the build
```

Any idea why it happens?

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was an issue of SBT. once i updated it from 0.13.5 to 0.13.8 the problem was gone.